# Resample-interpolate Pandas Dataframe, interpolate to NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a Pandas dataframe with datetime indices and a single column. The datetime indices are not regularly spaced (but ordered), and the corresponding values in the column are either numbers or NaN.

My goal is to interpolate these entries to hourly datetimes. I can do so with the following snippet:

```
df = dataframe.resample('H')
interpolated = df.interpolate(method='linear')
```

where *dataframe* is my raw dataframe, and *interpolated* is the interpolated dataframe.

This works perfectly well, but the problem is that this function seems to interpolate over the NaN values, which is not what I want. Ideally, I'd like the function to return NaN if it tries interpolate between two entries at least one of which is NaN (so if I interpolate between NaN and NaN: return NaN; if I interpolate between NaN and 5: return NaN; if I interpolate halfway between 3 and 5: return 4).

I could code my own brute-force interpolator which does this, but I'd much rather get my grip on Pandas. This seems like a pretty straightforward problem - does anyone know a method to achieve this?

Comment: Try `df.interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='outside)`

Comment: That's precisely what I have been looking for! Thanks a lot!